# Bind jqGrid from controller MVC3

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc-3, razor, jqgrid

I'm using `jqgrid` in my MVC3 application to bind the data in `Razor` view(.cshtml). The values are sent from the `controller` as `JSON`. But its not binding.

//Controller:

```
public JsonResult LoadData()
        {
            Connect objMC = new Connect();//Helper Class
            var collectionEmployee = objMC.LoadAllData();//Gets Employee Collection

            var jsonSerializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
            return Json(jsonSerializer.Serialize(collectionEmployee.AsQueryable<Product>().ToList<Product>()));
        }
```

//jqGrid:

```
jQuery("#jQGridDemo").jqGrid({
        url: '@(Url.Action("LoadData", "Home"))',
        datatype: "json",
        mtype: 'GET',
        colNames: ['ProductId', 'Name', 'AdminContent', 'ProductTemplate', 'CreatedOnUtc'],
        colModel: [{ name: 'ProductId', index: 'ProductId', width: 200, align: 'left', sorttype: 'int' },
                        { name: 'Name', index: 'Name', width: 200, align: 'left', sortable: true, editable: true },
                        { name: 'AdminContent', index: 'AdminContent', width: 200, align: 'left', sortable: true, editable: true },
                        { name: 'ProductTemplate', index: 'ProductTemplate', width: 200, editable: true, edittype: "select", editoptions: { value: "1:VariantsInGrid;2:SingleProductVariant;3:MultipleProducts" }, align: 'left' },
                        { name: 'CreatedOnUtc', index: 'CreatedOnUtc', width: 200, align: 'left', edittype: 'text', formatter: 'date', formatoptions: { newformat: 'm-d-Y' }, datefmt: 'm-d-Y',
                            editoptions: {
                                size: 10, maxlengh: 10,
                                dataInit: function (element) {
                                    $(element).datepicker({ dateFormat: 'yy.mm.dd' })
                                }
                            }, sortable: true, editable: true
                        }
            ],
        rowNum: 10,
        rowList: [10, 20, 30],
        pager: '#jQGridDemoPager',
        sortname: '_id',
        viewrecords: true,
        sortorder: 'desc',
        caption: "Grid",
        ignoreCase: true

    });


    jQuery("#jQGridDemo").jqGrid('filterToolbar', { stringResult: true, searchOnEnter: false, defaultSearch: "cn" });
```

//HTML:

```
<h2>
    New Grid</h2>
<table id="jQGridDemo">
</table>
```

The `controller` is getting called and the values are passed from the `controller` to `view`. But the values are not getting bind. Just i'm seeing an empty grid. This works perfect when i'm using a handler(.ashx) to load the grid.

Where i'm wrong?

Comment: Compare JSON code returned from ASXH and controller. Or post it here and we will try to help you.

Comment: Also check your controler for [HttpGet] or [HttpPost] Code!

Comment: @Phx: The code returned from ashx is now in the controller. I have used the same code here.

Comment: Yes I Know, but the JSON response may be different from ASHX than from a Controller. Anyway, did you check the HTTP Verbs accepted on your controller? jqgrid can be empty by json binding problems or because your controller is not returning any JSON (cause request is invalid).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks `@Oleg` for the all those suggestions given. Have done all those. But the `serializer` was blocking the code even after the below fix. Then i removed that to make the code work perfect.

I made that work like this,

//Controller:

```
 public JsonResult LoadData()
        {
            MONGOConnect objMC = new MONGOConnect();//Helper Class
            var collectionEmployee = objMC.LoadAllData();//Gets Employee Collection

            return Json(new
            {
                total = collectionEmployee.Count / 10,
                page = 1,
                records = collectionEmployee.Count,
                rows = collectionEmployee.AsQueryable<Product>().ToList<Product>()
            }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
```

//jqGrid:

```
 jQuery("#jQGridDemo").jqGrid({
        url: '@(Url.Action("LoadData", "Home"))',
        datatype: "json",
        mtype: 'GET',
        colNames: ['ProductId', 'Name', 'AdminContent', 'ProductTemplate', 'CreatedOnUtc'],
        colModel: [{ name: 'ProductId', index: 'ProductId', width: 200, align: 'left', sorttype: 'int' },
                        { name: 'Name', index: 'Name', width: 200, align: 'left', sortable: true, editable: true },
                        { name: 'AdminContent', index: 'AdminContent', width: 200, align: 'left', sortable: true, editable: true },
                        { name: 'ProductTemplate', index: 'ProductTemplate', width: 200, editable: true, edittype: "select", editoptions: { value: "1:VariantsInGrid;2:SingleProductVariant;3:MultipleProducts" }, align: 'left' },
                        { name: 'CreatedOnUtc', index: 'CreatedOnUtc', width: 200, align: 'left', edittype: 'text', formatter: 'date', formatoptions: { newformat: 'm-d-Y' }, datefmt: 'm-d-Y',
                            editoptions: {
                                size: 10, maxlengh: 10,
                                dataInit: function (element) {
                                    $(element).datepicker({ dateFormat: 'yy.mm.dd' })
                                }
                            }, sortable: true, editable: true
                        }
            ],

                        jsonReader: {
                            root: 'rows',
                            total: 'total',
                            page: 'page',
                            records: 'records',
                            cell: 'cell',
                            id: 'id',
                            repeatitems: false
                        },
        rowNum: 10,
        rowList: [10, 20, 30],
        pager: '#jQGridDemoPager',
        sortname: '_id',
        viewrecords: true,
        loadonce:true,
        sortorder: 'desc',
        caption: "Grid",
        gridview: true,
        autoencode: true,
        ignoreCase: true

    });
```

Added a `JSON reader` in the grid code and when returning from the `controller` i assigned to that. Idea is got from `@NandaIN` Code. Thanks for him also.

Comment: You wrote "the serializer was blocking the code even after the below fix". Do you have seen some error message about this? Do you tried to set breakpoints inside of `LoadData` function? Do you tried to use `mtype: 'POST'` instead of `mtype: 'GET'`? Could you include declaration of the class `Product`? By the way you can return array or list of `Product` items from `LoadData` function. `new { total, ...}` is not needed if you use `loadonce: true` option. You can use Developer Tools of Internet Explorer (press F12 to start use Network tab) to trace HTTP traffic between jqGrid and MVC Controller.

Comment: @Oleg: I didn't c any error message. But as you said i removed the serializer and ran the code. It worked.

Comment: @Oleg: Can you also look into this question of mine please. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24800860/pass-updated-value-from-jqgrid-popup-to-controller-mvc3

Answer (score 2):

The MVC code which you posted don't allow HTTP GET. You have to use `mtype: 'POST'` parameter of jqGrid or use `JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet` parameter of [Json](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee430920(v=vs.118).aspx).

You should don't use `JavaScriptSerializer` to make **manual** serialization. `Controller.Json` Method do the serialization for you. The usage of `JavaScriptSerializer.Serialize` is the main your error in my opinion.

You don't posted the code which defined `Product` class. You should varify that the values of `name` property of column definition in `colModel` are the same as the name of properties or fields of the `Product` class.

Your current code don't have any server side paging. You just returns *all* data at once. In the case you should use `loadonce: true` option of jqGrid.

You should add `gridview: true` and `autoencode: true`.

You should add `<div id="jQGridDemoPager"></div>` somewhere of your page (for example direct after `<table id="jQGridDemo"></table>`).

If `ProductId` property of the `Product` class contains **unique** value then you should add `key: true` property to the definition of `ProductId` property of `colModel`.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to bind each value in controller. try this, may be this will work

```
 public JsonResult LoadData()
        {

           Connect objMC = new Connect();//Helper Class
            var collectionEmployee = objMC.LoadAllData();//Gets Employee Collection

                if ( null == collectionEmployee || collectionEmployee .Count == 0)
                    return Json(0, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
                else
                    return Json(new
                    {
                        TotalCount = (collectionEmployee == null) ? 0 : collectionEmployee .Count,
                        Data = (from item in collectionEmployee 
                                select new
                                {
                                    ProductId= item.ProductId,
                                    Name= item.Name,
                                    AdminContent= item.AdminContent,
                                    ProductTemplate= item.ProductTemplate,
                                    CreatedOnUtc=item.CreatedOnUtc
                                }).ToList()

                    }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
```