# Pass parameters in Edit Url of jqGrid for Form Editing

Tags: jquery, ajax, jqgrid

I am using `jgGrid` form editing in which I am updating the edited values. When I click submit the `editurl` gets called. In that case in my scenario I have to pass two parameters to Controller.

//jqGrid Code:

```
    var colname = [];
    var colHeader = [];
    var gridData;


var selectedValue;
var multipleSource;
var colValues = [];
var columns = [{ name: 'Workflow Name', width: '200px' }, { name: 'Workflow Category', width: '150px' }, { name: 'Status', width: '100px' }, { name: 'Workflow Owner', width: '150px' }];

$.ajax({
            url: '@Url.Action("LoadColumns","Home")',
           // url: "/Home/LoadColumns",
            data: { 'workflowId': selectedValue, 'status': $('#Status option:selected').val(), 'customView': $('#CustomViews option:selected').val() },
            datatype: 'json',
            type: 'GET',
            success: OnComplete,
            error: OnFail
        });
        function OnComplete(result) {
          //  debugger;
            gridData = $.parseJSON(result)
            colHeader = [];
            colname = [];
            $.each(gridData.Table1, function () {

            colHeader.push(this.Name);

            switch (this.Datatype) {

                case 'int':
                    colname.push({ name: this.Name, index: this.Name, width: 130, align: 'left', sortable: true, editable: false, sorttype: 'int' });
                    break;
                case 'String':
                    colname.push({ name: this.Name, index: this.Name, width: 130, align: 'left', sortable: true, editable: true });
                    break;
                case 'DateTime':
                    colname.push({
                        name: this.Name, search: true, index: this.Name, width: 130, stype: "text", editable: true, searchoptions: {

                            dataInit: function (el) {

                                $(el).datepicker({
                                    dateFormat: 'm/d/y', maxDate: 0, changeMonth: true, changeYear: true, onSelect: function (dateText, inst) {
                                        setTimeout(function () {
                                            $('#jQGridDemo')[0].triggerToolbar();
                                        }, 50);
                                    }
                                });

                            }
                        }, editoptions: {
                            dataInit: function (el) {

                                $(el).datepicker({
                                    dateFormat: 'm/d/y', maxDate: 0, changeMonth: true, changeYear: true
                                });

                            }
                        }
                    });
                    break;
                case 'dropdown':

                    colname.push({

                        name: this.Name, index: this.Name, width: 130, edittype: "select", formatter: 'select',
                        cellattr: function (rowId, val, rawObject, cm, rdata) {
                            var strVal = [];
                            strVal = val.split("_");

                            if (rawObject[cm.name + "_Title"] == "") {
                              //  debugger;
                                return 'title="' + strVal[0].toString() + '"';
                            }
                            else
                                return 'title="' + val + ' (' + rawObject[cm.name + "_Title"] + ')"';

                        },
                        editoptions: { value: ':Select;' + this.ValueList.slice(0, -1) }, stype: 'select'
                                , searchoptions: { value: ':All;' + this.ValueList.slice(0, -1) }, align: 'left', sortable: true, editable: true
                    });
                    break;
                default:
                    colname.push({ name: this.Name, index: this.Name, width: 130, align: 'left', sortable: true, editable: true });
                    break;
                    break;
            }

        });

 jQuery("#jQGridDemo").jqGrid({
            data: gridData.BuildTransactionsDataTable,
            datatype: "local",
            hoverrows: false,
            colNames: colHeader,
            colModel: colname,
            id: 'TransactionId',
            localReader: {
                root: 'rows',
                id: 'TransactionId',

                repeatitems: false
            },
            rowNum: 10,
            rowList: [10, 20, 30],
            pager: '#jQGridDemoPager',
            sortname: '_id',
            viewrecords: true,
            loadonce: true,
            sortorder: 'desc',
            caption: "Grid",
            gridview: true,
            autoencode: true,
            ignoreCase: true

        });

jQuery("#jQGridDemo").jqGrid('filterToolbar', { stringResult: true, searchOperators: true, searchOnEnter: false, defaultSearch: "cn" });


        $('#jQGridDemo').jqGrid('navGrid', '#jQGridDemoPager',
                   {
                       edit: true,
                       add: true,
                       del: false,
                       search: true,
                       searchtext: "Search",
                       addtext: "Add",
                       edittext: "Edit",
                       deltext: "Delete"
                   },
                    { multipleSearch: true },
                     //{

                     {   //EDIT
                         //                       height: 300,
                         //                       width: 400,
                         //                       top: 50,
                         //                       left: 100,
                         //                       dataheight: 280,
                         closeOnEscape: true, //Closes the popup on pressing escape key
                         reloadAfterSubmit: true,
                         drag: true,

                         afterSubmit: function (response, postdata) {
                             debugger;
                             if (response.responseText == "") {

                                 $(this).jqGrid('setGridParam', { datatype: 'json' }).trigger('reloadGrid'); //Reloads the grid after edit
                                 return [true, '']
                             }
                             else {

                                 $(this).jqGrid('setGridParam', { datatype: 'json' }).trigger('reloadGrid'); //Reloads the grid after edit
                                 return [false, response.responseText]//Captures and displays the response text on th Edit window
                             }
                         },

                         onclickSubmit: function (response, postdata) {
                             debugger;
                             var resultGriddata = JSON.stringify(postdata);
                             var resultColumndata = JSON.stringify(gridData.Table1);
                             $.ajax({
                                 url: "/Home/UpdateData",
                                 datatype: 'json',
                                 data: { 'gridData': resultGriddata, 'columnData': resultColumndata },
                                 type: 'POST',
                                 success: OnComplete,
                                 error: OnFail
                             });
                             function OnComplete(result) {
                                 alert(result);
                             }
                         },
                         editData: {
                             TransactionId: function () {

                                 var sel_id = $('#jQGridDemo').jqGrid('getGridParam', 'selrow');
                                 var value = $('#jQGridDemo').jqGrid('getCell', sel_id, '_id');
                                 return value;

                             }
                         }


                     },
               {
                   closeAfterAdd: true, //Closes the add window after add
                   afterSubmit: function (response, postdata) {
                       debugger;
                       if (response.responseText == "") {

                           $(this).jqGrid('setGridParam', { datatype: 'json' }).trigger('reloadGrid')//Reloads the grid after Add
                           return [true, '']
                       }
                       else {
                           alert(response);
                           $(this).jqGrid('setGridParam', { datatype: 'json' }).trigger('reloadGrid')//Reloads the grid after Add
                           return [false, response.responseText]
                       }
                   }
               },
               {   //DELETE
                   closeOnEscape: true,
                   closeAfterDelete: true,
                   reloadAfterSubmit: true,
                   closeOnEscape: true,
                   drag: true,
                   afterSubmit: function (response, postdata) {
                       if (response.responseText == "") {

                           $("#jQGridDemo").trigger("reloadGrid", [{ current: true }]);
                           return [false, response.responseText]
                       }
                       else {
                           $(this).jqGrid('setGridParam', { datatype: 'json' }).trigger('reloadGrid');
                           return [true, response.responseText]
                       }
                   },
                   delData: {
                       TransactionId: function () {
                           var sel_id = $('#jQGridDemo').jqGrid('getGridParam', 'selrow');
                           var value = $('#jQGridDemo').jqGrid('getCell', sel_id, '_id');
                           return value;
                       }
                   }
               },
               {//SEARCH
                   closeOnEscape: true

               }
        );
  }
```

In this code I have passed three parameters which makes the grid loaded:

//Controller Code:

```
 [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult UpdateData(string gridData, string columnData)
        {

            return Content("Success");

        }
```

I have tried it in two ways:

**1. Adding EditData:**
                         I have tried adding the `editData` below the `editurl` and tried passing a single parameter. But i got null as a result in the Controller.

```
 editData: { _dokdata: function () { return JSON.stringify(gridData); } }
```

**2. Passing data in onclickSubmit:**
                             I have tried posting the data to controller in the `onclickSubmit` event. Like,

```
 onclickSubmit: function (response, postdata) {

                             postdata.extraParam = gridData;
                             var resultGriddata = JSON.stringify(postdata);
                             var resultColumndata = JSON.stringify(gridData.Table1);
                             $.ajax({
                                 url: "/Home/UpdateData",
                                 datatype: 'json',
                                 data: { 'gridData': resultGriddata,     'columnData':resultColumndata },
                                 type: 'POST',
                                 success: OnComplete,
                                 error: OnFail
                             });
                             function OnComplete(result) {
                                 alert(result);
                             }
                         },
```

Now in the `onclickSubmit` I have to pass both parameters and get those values into the controller. Right now the controller is getting called with both parameters with values as expected(the data). I am not sure of the other events in the code.

But after the process in code behind I get error in the edit popup saying that **"Url is not set"**. So I tried in many ways giving like `'clientarray'` for `editurl` and `cellsubmit`, but nothing helped.

It was said that in my search, all should be given for `InlineEdit` and not for `FormEdit`. Not sure i'm where i'm wrong.

How can I make this work without showing the error in the popup?

SampleData:

```
{"Table1":[{"Name":"Have Queries","Datatype":"String","ValueList":"","ValueId":"139646","ValueType":"F"},{"Name":"Assign to Karthik","Datatype":"String","ValueList":"","ValueId":"139665","ValueType":"F"},{"Name":"Field Format","Datatype":"DateTime","ValueList":"","ValueId":"141803","ValueType":"F"},{"Name":"URLFields","Datatype":"String","ValueList":"","ValueId":"447592","ValueType":"F"},{"Name":"Testing","Datatype":"String","ValueList":"","ValueId":"705958","ValueType":"F"},{"Name":"Start Task","Datatype":"dropdown","ValueList":"In Process:In Process;Completed:Completed;Re-Work Required:Re-Work Required;Assigned:Assigned;Not Required:Not Required;","ValueId":"139584","ValueType":"T"},{"Name":"Create Credentials","Datatype":"dropdown","ValueList":"In Process:In Process;Completed:Completed;Re-Work Required:Re-Work Required;Assigned:Assigned;Not Required:Not Required;","ValueId":"139585","ValueType":"T"},{"Name":"Branching and Mapping","Datatype":"dropdown","ValueList":"In Process:In Process;Completed:Completed;Re-Work Required:Re-Work Required;Assigned:Assigned;Not Required:Not Required;","ValueId":"139586","ValueType":"T"},{"Name":"Application Walkthrough","Datatype":"dropdown","ValueList":"In Process:In Process;Completed:Completed;Re-Work Required:Re-Work Required;Assigned:Assigned;Not Required:Not Required;","ValueId":"139587","ValueType":"T"},{"Name":"Call","Datatype":"dropdown","ValueList":"In Process:In Process;Completed:Completed;Re-Work Required:Re-Work Required;Assigned:Assigned;Not Required:Not Required;","ValueId":"139588","ValueType":"T"},{"Name":"Queries","Datatype":"dropdown","ValueList":"In Process:In Process;Completed:Completed;Re-Work Required:Re-Work Required;Assigned:Assigned;Not Required:Not Required;","ValueId":"139589","ValueType":"T"},{"Name":"Development Ready","Datatype":"dropdown","ValueList":"In Process:In Process;Completed:Completed;Re-Work Required:Re-Work Required;Assigned:Assigned;Not Required:Not Required;","ValueId":"139591","ValueType":"T"},{"Name":"Assign","Datatype":"dropdown","ValueList":"In Process:In Process;Completed:Completed;Re-Work Required:Re-Work Required;Assigned:Assigned;Not Required:Not Required;","ValueId":"139666","ValueType":"T"},{"Name":"Check Developer","Datatype":"dropdown","ValueList":"In Process:In Process;Completed:Completed;Re-Work Required:Re-Work Required;Assigned:Assigned;Not Required:Not Required;","ValueId":"139701","ValueType":"T"}],"Table2":[{"TransactionId":"141090","TransactionStatus":"29607","StartDate":"1/18/1900 5:02:00 PM","Have Queries":"Y","Assign to Karthik":"Yes","Field Format":"","URLFields":"","Testing":"","Start Task":"Completed","Start Task_Title":"43_False","Create Credentials":"Completed","Create Credentials_Title":"_False","Branching and Mapping":"Completed","Branching and Mapping_Title":"2_False","Application Walkthrough":null,"Application Walkthrough_Title":null,"Call":"Completed","Call_Title":"_False","Queries":null,"Queries_Title":null,"Development Ready":null,"Development Ready_Title":null,"Assign":null,"Assign_Title":null,"Check Developer":null,"Check Developer_Title":null},{"TransactionId":"141101","TransactionStatus":"29607","StartDate":"5/10/2013 12:00:00 AM","Have Queries":"N","Assign to Karthik":"Yes","Field Format":"","URLFields":"","Testing":"","Start Task":"Completed","Start Task_Title":"43_False","Create Credentials":"In Process","Create Credentials_Title":"2_True","Branching and Mapping":"Completed","Branching and Mapping_Title":"_False","Application Walkthrough":"Completed","Application Walkthrough_Title":"_False","Call":"Completed","Call_Title":"_False","Queries":null,"Queries_Title":null,"Development Ready":null,"Development Ready_Title":null,"Assign":null,"Assign_Title":null,"Check Developer":null,"Check Developer_Title":null}]}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all you should decide which editing mode you use. If you want to use [form editing](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:form_editing) then no `cellEdit: true` option should exist in your code. Yo used wrong option `celledit` instead of `cellEdit`, so it will be just ignored, but the existence of such options makes the code more difficult to read. By the way `cellsubmit` option which you mention in your question (for example `cellsubmit: "remote"`) works only in case of [cell editing](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:cell_editing) which required the usage of `cellEdit: true`.

The code which you posted don't contains any form editing code. It's unclear whether you use `navGrid` with some options or you `formatter: "actions"` with `formatoptions: {editformbutton: true}` or calls [editGridRow](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:form_editing#editgridrow) method directly ... Which options and how exactly you use form editing is unclear from your question so one have to guess what you do.

If you decide to use form editing then **you should place `editData` in correct place**. `editData` is **not jqGrid option** (see [here](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:options)). It's parameter (option/property) of [editGridRow](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:form_editing#editgridrow) method (see [here](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:form_editing#properties)). Depend on how you use form editing you should place it in the corresponding place. For example if you use [navGrid](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:navigator#definition) then the 3-d and 4-th parameters of it (see `prmEdit` and `prmAdd`) allows you to specify the option forwarded to `editGridRow` by `navGrid` if the user click Edit or Add button of the navigator bar. The code which you posted in [the question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24800860/315935) uses correct place for `editData`, but "adding the `editData` below the `editurl`" (see the text of your question) is the wrong way.

You wrote "i have to pass 2 parameters to Controller" (but the code of `UpdateData` action controller which you posted contains *only one* parameter `gridData`). You don't posted `colModel` which makes more difficult to understand you (by the way you used misunderstanding names: `colModel: colname`, but `colName` option have another value `colHeader`), but probably exactly one column from `colModel` have `editable: true` property. In the case the usage of form editing seems me really not the best choice and usage cell editing could be more simple. To use it you need add `cellsubmit: "remote"`, `cellEdit: true` and `cellurl: "/Home/UpdateData"`. In the case jqGrid will send to the server (to `cellurl`) *3* parameters (see [the documentation](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:cell_editing#what_is_posted_to_the_server)):

- The editing data with the name like the value of `name` property in `colModel`.
- rowid under the name `id`. One can use `prmNames` [option](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:options) to change the `id` name. For example `prmNames: {id: "TransactionId"}` will change the name of rowid to `TransactionId`.
- Fixed string `oper=edit`. One can change the names by usage `prmNames`. For example `prmNames: {oper: "myOper", editoper: "myEdit"}` will change `oper=edit` to `myOper=myEdit`.

Additionally one can use `beforeSubmitCell` and `serializeCellData` to customize the data:

```js
beforeSubmitCell: function (rowid, name, value, iRow, iCol) {
    return {gridData: gridData};
},
serializeCellData: function (postdata) {
    return JSON.stringify(postdata);
}
```

You can change `serializeCellData` in any other way which you need. For example

```
serializeCellData: function (postdata) {
    return {
        gridData: JSON.stringify(postdata.gridData),
        columnData: JSON.stringify(postdata.columnNameFromColModel)
    };
}
```

Comment: Since this grid is to be viewed in mobile and to make the edit more visualize i need to use form editing. Its showing me "Url is not set" but i'm able to receive the values in code behind. In the UI it shows me the error. Why?

Comment: @SanthoshKumar: You should post the code which corresponds **form editing**. As I worte in my answer: 1) The code which you posted have no line which corresponds form editing. 2) You should include the code which shows exactly **where** you placed `editData`, `onclickSubmit` etc. and the definition of **colModel** (at least `columnData` column).

Comment: Updated the question. Kindly help.

Comment: @SanthoshKumar: The code still don't contains `colModel` which is important (see my previous comment). It's not good to use `.trigger('reloadGrid')` inside of `afterSubmit`. The call of `$.ajax` should be also removed from `onclickSubmit`. **The current code have no `editurl: "/Home/UpdateData"`**. `UpdateData` contains no `id` so you will have no information *which row* will be edited. If you want to send `_id` (`TransactionId`) as the parameter of `UpdateData` then you should verify **how you fill the data in the grid**. If you fill the data correctly then rowid (send as `id`) contains it.

Comment: Added now. Let me know anything is needed.

Comment: Also updated the question. But haven't changed anything in the code. Just i need to get rid of the error thrown in the popup and get the values updated.

Comment: **How you fill the data in the grid**? If you fill the data correctly then rowid (send as `id`) contains it. Could you include test data with 2 rows? Have the data `_id` or `TransactionId` property or both? By the way it's very bad to use `name` of `colModel` which have special meta-characters like spaces.

Comment: Its a very big process in the code behind and its complicated to reproduce.

Comment: What to reproduce? I asked you to include test data with 2 rows. For example `[{"_id":123, "TransactionId":986, "Workflow Name": "wn1", "Workflow Category": "wc1", "Status": "OK", "Workflow Owner": "o1"}, {"_id":456, "TransactionId":765, "Workflow Name": "wn2", "Workflow Category": "wc2", "Status": "Failed", "Workflow Owner": "o2"}]`. Corresponds it to your data or some properties? **The first error in your code: it have no `editurl` option.** Other error you use `var value = $('#jQGridDemo').jqGrid('getCell', sel_id, '_id');` and `sortname: '_id'`, but `colModel` have no `name: "_id"` column.

Comment: @SanthoshKumar: The next error: no column (see `columns` which you included) contains `editable: true` property. The next error you should don't define `colModel` with `name` having spaces or any meta-characters such as  `!"#$%&'()*+,./:;<=>?@[\]^`{|}~` (you use `name: 'Workflow Name'` for example) because 1) `name` value will be used to build `id` values which should not have the characters. 2) the names of parameters of `UpdateData` should be *the same* as `name` value of editable columns. Try to declare in C# variable with the name `Workflow Name` (with spaces) or class with the property.

Comment: Have added the sample data in question. I have added edit url first but thought of using the onclickSubmit i removed that. Not sure how to modify the code to make it work.

Comment: I could able to receive the desired data in the controller. Not sure why i'm getting the "Url not set" error in the popup after executing the submit functionality.